# cURL shows blank page

Tags: php, curl

my curl code show me a blank page

```
 <?
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://mysite/scripts/showsomething.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$core = explode('<!--- BEGIN -->', $result); 
$main = explode('<!--- END -->', $core[1]);
echo $main[0]; 
?>
```

this code works fine on localhost, but not on server...

Comment: Do you administer the other server? if not, is there a possibility that your ip was blocked by the remote server?

Comment: i don't know if you server support php short tag <? . Please check else try using <?php

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons behind your problem.

1) Change `<?` into `<?php` and see whether it works or not.

2) For a short test, run this code from your server and check whether it shows you the output or not.

```
<?php
  echo "sabuj";
?>
```

3) Some site seek for useragent string on their website request. When they found no useragent, they use to return blank page. You can overcome this with setting an useragent like below.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
```

4) Another thing you can do is, access the server with `ssh` client(if you have any) and run the url with `wget` tool and see whether you can download your page or not.

```
wget "http://yoursite/page/blabla/...php"
```

5) Finally, run your curl code with verbose mode enabled. It will help you to debug your curl requests.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code...**

```
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 10;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       var_dump($data);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: i use
echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
and get 
Array
7
couldn't connect to host

Comment: @user3175158 did you user any valid URL in place of $url?

Comment: @user3175158 if its working with google. then there must be a problem with the url. The code is working just fine..

Answer (score 0):

Turn your error reporting all the way to 11.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will tell you a little more about the issue you are facing. The most common culprit when working with curl on a dev environment and moving to a server is a missing curl package.

You can check to see if you have curl installed by doing the following:

```
if(!function_exists('curl_version')) {
    throw new Exception('Curl package missing');
}
```

Thus "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in..." is a very common error that is thrown.

Some additional debugging tips are to..

1. print_r the response of curl_exec($handle);
2. print_r curl_error($handle) this will give you a curl error code.
3. setup a curl proxy using set_opt and CURLOPT_PROXY, set the value to your ip:port, open the port 8888 on your router and install charles proxy. This will show you an exact printout of the request and response.

Comment: Change your url out for the google home page. 'http://google.com' add the following line. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

If you still cannot connect to host you have a networking issue. ie a firewall preventing the connection.

Comment: if you copy and past the url from your php code can you reach it in a browser as well as ping it from the php server?

Answer (score 0):

I've read the previous answers and it seems that your code is fine but problem is connectivity to remote server, please try this:

```
<?
//debug
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//debug end

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://mysite/scripts/showsomething.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo result;
?>
```

what does it output ?

Notes:

Do you administer the other server?
if not, is there a possibility that your ip was blocked by the remote server?
Does script `http://mysite/scripts/showsomething.php` contains any errors ?
If you're able to edit it, please enable php errors on `showsomething.php` by adding the following code at the top of it :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by adding the following code.
The problem is SSL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I hope it helps.